# cannot populate view in multithreading environment in android

Tags: android

**Error**
05-12 11:56:45.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(505): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

**what i have done**

i have a list view inside my activity and i need to populate the listview by doing the following:
`mylistview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());`

now there is already too much pressure on my UI thread so , thought of calling this method inside a AsynTask.

**Another problem**

there is a progress dialog that shows in my acitivity when the user clicks the button to populate the listview. when i put everything inside one thread the progress dialog does not show. i had asked a question on stackoverflow about why the progress dialog does not show and i had got a reply saying that i need to put all the extra tasks inside another thread.

**i have also read the *updating UI in android* given on android developer website:**
but over there all we do is make a new runnable and post the runnable to the Handler of the UI thread so that when the UI is free, the runnable will be executed.
But how does the above solve my purpose? i mean the UI thread is still executing the instructions.

The only way i can take the load of the UI thread is if i make another thread and put all the work over there... but android does not allow this?

- what is wrong with my understanding(if there is anything wrong)?
- How do i solve this problem

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does allow you to put the extra work in a different thread AND publish the results on the UI thread, using AsyncTask. Add the UI update stage in the `onPostExecute()` method of the AsyncTask and you should be good-to-go. `onPostExecute()` is performed on the UI thread, the example in the [AsyncTask Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a great one.

Also, if you build your application properly, and don't use graphics a lot, there should not be too much work for the UI thread during the application run. Move everything that doesn't absolutely bound to the UI on a separate thread. AsyncTask is a very convenient way to do it.

Comment: then my purpose is defeated. i want to populate a listview and i have put that inside async task. i am only calling the setadapter method iniside the doinbackground() method. this is taking a long time as my list is very long.

Comment: Divide it into two parts: `CustomAdapter cust = new CustomAdapter()` in background thread, and `mylistview.setAdapter(cust);` in main thread. It will probably help.

Comment: when is the listview populated? when i make the adapter or when i set the adapter?

Comment: When you set it. My suggestion is to move the creation of the adapter to the back task.

Comment: let me make my question clear. if the listview is populated when i set the adapter, also at the same time when the UI is showing a progress dialog to the user because the listview is being populated in the back, would the UI thread be able to do these simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is the correct way to solve your problem. Where you are running into difficulty is exactly *what* to put into the `AsyncTask`. Call `mylistview.setAdapter();` from the `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` methods. So do something like this:

```
 void setProgress(Integer progress){ myprogressbar.setValue(progress); }
 void setAdapter(CustomAdapter result){ mylistview.setAdapter(result); }
 private class LongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, CustomAdapter> {
     protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
         CustomAdapter res = null;
         // do all the work to BUILD the custom adapter, calling publishProgress() as progress gets made
         publishProgress(<progress value>);
         return res;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
          setProgress(progress);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(CustomAdapter result) {
        setAdapter(result);
     }
 }
```

That should fix the threading issue and let you set the progress bar.

Comment: when i make a runnable and post it on the UI thread's handler, is that better than AsyncTask approach for the situation? PS : i am using a progress dialog and not a progress bar. i don't need to update or send progress.

Comment: A Runnable posted to the UI thread's handler will block the UI thread if the operation that fetches the adapter data takes too long: your application will then freeze. The AsyncTask creates a separate thread, performs the long running operation in that thread BUT gives you the hooks to do the UI changes on the right thread without blocking the UI thread. You want to use it. It doesn't matter if it is a progress bar or progress dialog: any changes to the progress value MUST happen on the UI thread or your progress bar will continue to throw the same exceptions. Use `onProgressUpdate` for that.